# Is there a way to access a Date as milliseconds since epoch (Date.getTime()) in mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

Mongodb provides lots of '`Date Aggregation Operators`' such as `$dayOfYear`, `$dayOf Month`, and `$millisecond`. The `$millisecond` function just returns the milliseconds of the time stamp with a range of 0-999.

Is there a way to access a `Date` object as milliseconds since epoch in aggregation pipeline?

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can $subtract the epoch date and the result will be your date milliseconds since epoch:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project : {
        "dateInMillis" : {$subtract : ["$date", new Date("1-1-1970")] }
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around. Seems like an odd way of getting the value but it works

Comment: @NathanReese It's not odd at all once you realize that the underlying BSON date is actually an epoch timestamp. Which is all this does. The **difference** between **now** and the **beginning** in milliseconds. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Make sure to parse date as UTC 'new Date(Date.UTC('1-1-1970'))'

Comment: new Date(0) should also give you the 'beginning of time' epoch

Comment: @AchintyaAshok and `new Date(0)` also ensures that local/server time zone doesn't cause any issues

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can add an aggregation pipeline.

[image: here's how you can add in aggregationPipleine]